# Select Statement on Temporary Table to Display Rows Currently In and Not in Live Table

Tags: mysql, sql

Start with an array that holds values that are going into a database table called `producttags`.

```
$newproducttags = array ('Green', 'Synthetic', 'Clearance');
```

and another variable which holds its `Foreign Key ID` connected to another table called `products`

Which looks similar to this

```
╔═════╦═══════╦═════════════════════╗
║ id  ║  MPN  ║     createdtime     ║
╠═════╬═══════╬═════════════════════╣
║ ... ║ ...   ║ ...                 ║
║ 517 ║ 0WV12 ║ 2019-01-05 02:42:33 ║
║ ... ║ ...   ║ ...                 ║
╚═════╩═══════╩═════════════════════╝
```

/

```
// in this case $fk_id = 517;
$fk_id = $this->db->run("SELECT id FROM `products` WHERE `MPN` = ?", [$MPN])->fetchColumn();
```

In doing the query `SELECT * FROM producttags WHERE productID = 517` it brings back

```
╔═══════════╦══════════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ productID ║     Tag      ║    lastmodified     ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║       517 ║ Blue         ║ 2019-02-02 15:00:23 ║
║       517 ║ Synthetic    ║ 2019-02-02 15:00:23 ║
║       517 ║ Monthly Sale ║ 2019-02-02 15:00:23 ║
╚═══════════╩══════════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

I am attempting to create a temporary table with the contents of `$newproducttags` and then compare it to the current existing `producttags` table.

To do so is easy enough.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE producttags_temp AS 
SELECT Tag AS Tag_temp, productID AS productID_temp, 
lastmodified AS lastmodified_Temp FROM producttags LIMIT 0;
```

Use a foreach loop to insert the new product tags from the values in `$newproducttags` into the temporary table

```
foreach ($prodTagArr as $prodTag) {
$this->data = $this->db->run("INSERT INTO `producttags_temp` 
    (`Tag_temp`, `productID_temp`, `lastmodified_Temp`) 
        VALUES (?, ?, NOW())", 
             [$prodTag, $fk_id]);
}
```

This works as expected. Doing a SELECT * FROM `producttags_temp` brings back:

```
╔═════════╦════════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ id_temp ║  Tag_temp  ║  lastmodified_temp  ║
╠═════════╬════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║     517 ║ Green      ║ 2019-02-03 12:00:55 ║
║     517 ║ Synthetic  ║ 2019-02-03 12:00:55 ║
║     517 ║ Clearance  ║ 2019-02-03 12:00:55 ║
╚═════════╩════════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

Looks good so far, right?

Now that challenge of comparing the two tables illustrated above and outputting the comparison between the two.

I swear this should be easy. It seems like it should be easy. My desirable output is *something* like this (or NULL values on a `producttags` and `producttags_temp` table would be fine too -- just an output that can show me a comparison of the current and new.

So like this, but does not necessarily have to be as such:

```
╔═══════════╦══════════════╦════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ productID ║     Tag      ║ status ║    lastmodified     ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════╬════════╬═════════════════════╣
║       517 ║ Blue         ║      0 ║ 2019-02-02 15:00:23 ║
║       517 ║ Monthly Sale ║      0 ║ 2019-02-02 15:00:23 ║
║       517 ║ Green        ║      1 ║ 2019-02-03 12:00:55 ║
║       517 ║ Synthetic    ║      1 ║ 2019-02-03 12:00:55 ║
║       517 ║ Clearance    ║      1 ║ 2019-02-03 12:00:55 ║
╚═══════════╩══════════════╩════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

I don't know how much you all want me to muddle the thread with failed attempted.

```
SELECT * FROM producttags_temp  WHERE producttags_temp.Tag_temp 
NOT IN ( SELECT producttags.Tag FROM producttags 
WHERE producttags.productID = producttags_temp.productID_temp );
```

Works to bring back results that are in `producttags_temp` / `$newproducttags`

```
╔════════════════╦═══════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ productID_temp ║ Tag_temp  ║  lastmodified_temp  ║
╠════════════════╬═══════════╬═════════════════════╣
║            517 ║ Green     ║ 2019-02-03 12:00:55 ║
║            517 ║ Clearance ║ 2019-02-03 12:00:55 ║
╚════════════════╩═══════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

I'm assuming some sort of JOIN is required, but I'm having the hardest time finding a workable solution. This query works but doesn't include any of the `Tag_temp` values, only pre-existing non-temporary table rows.

```
SELECT * FROM producttags_temp 
WHERE producttags_temp.Tag_temp 
IN ( SELECT producttags.Tag FROM producttags 
WHERE producttags.productID = producttags_temp.productID_temp )
```

// like this but without timestamp

```
╔═══════════╦══════════════╗
║ productID ║     Tag      ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════╣
║       517 ║ Blue         ║
║       517 ║ Monthly Sale ║
║       517 ║ Synthetic    ║
║       517 ║ Blue         ║
║       517 ║ Monthly Sale ║
║       517 ║ Synthetic    ║
║       517 ║ Blue         ║
║       517 ║ Monthly Sale ║
║       517 ║ Synthetic    ║
╚═══════════╩══════════════╝
```

This seems like it should be an ever so simple join, but I've tried literally several different options and none seem to provide the output I want. Can anyone please shed some light on this, it's a bit maddening :)
Thank you.

Comment: What does the `status` mean in your expected output?

Comment: It's just something I've used in the past to indicate a boolean true or false. 0 Means it is not in the newest `$producttagsarray` / `producttags_temp` table, `1` indicates that it is in both.  As stated though perhaps a better option might be to somehow JOIN the table across the actual table and temporary table columns and display null values to compare the two tables as such (but I can't get a successful query to do this as of yet).. the `status` idea is just one example of a solution to indicate the comparison.

Comment: Why are you using a `SELECT` to create the temporary table if you're not actually selecting any rows?

Comment: Is the `ID` column in your table supposed to be `productID`?

Comment: When I try your query I get 8 rows of results. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h1TdK8LGzeCiB9PH4QSvZM/0

Comment: I can't figure out what you are actually trying to accomplish.  You have all this discussion about temporary tables that is just irrelevant to the results you want to achieve.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Is it? Honestly this has been tough I've been trying to *figure out* the best way to achieve this, I thought that to be temporary tables, is where I'm at now.  What I'm trying to achieve is get a SELECT query so that I can use that information into a PHP condition to (for those with a `status` `0`) `DELETE`/`INSERT` into a history table, and do a `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` on `producttags` table for present comparisons (`status` `1`)... @Barmar Yes it is I'll make that edit. That result, interesting- thank you for that. Figuring out why now. Appreciate all the replies.

Comment: @BrianBruman . . . You have an array of product tags and something called an `$fk_id` (I don't know what that is).  You then have data in your database.  And you want particular results.  Seeing examples of the data and the results would really help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thought I did alright providing examples of the data. I posted what my current `producttags` table looks like ( the rows with the foreign key / 517 anyways) -- and `producttags_temp` with new entries.  These are the two I'm looking to compare.  I didn't think any other methodology was relevant, if it is, please let me know I can gladly provide. I did edit the original question to show where `$fk_id` comes from (just a `SELECT` statement on the products table for the `id`), if that's relevant great! But my thought was just needing to compare the tag table to the tag_temp table.

Comment: @Barmar You are correct, thanks for pointing that out. I fixed that and am able to get back all 8 rows, but as you can see the 8 rows that are outputted does not include the new `Tag_temp`'s from the `producttags_temp` table, only duplicating the current ones in the `producttags` table.. Still trying to work out a query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this query will give you the results you want. It first creates a list of all the tags in `producttags` and `producttags_temp`, which it `LEFT JOIN`s to `producttags` and `producttags_temp`, using `COALESCE` to select values from `producttags_temp` in preference to those from `producttags` (for the case when a tag is present in both tables). A status value is created by checking whether the `productId_temp` value from `producttags_temp` is NOT NULL, indicating a newer entry has been found in that table.

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(p2.productId_temp, p1.productId) AS productId,
    COALESCE(p2.Tag_temp, p1.Tag) AS Tag,
    p2.productId_temp IS NOT NULL AS status,
    COALESCE(p2.lastmodified_temp, p1.lastmodified) AS lastmodified
FROM (SELECT Tag FROM producttags
      UNION
      SELECT Tag_temp FROM producttags_temp
      ) t
LEFT JOIN producttags p1 ON p1.Tag = t.Tag
LEFT JOIN producttags_temp p2 ON p2.Tag_temp = t.Tag
ORDER BY status
```

Output:

```
productId   Tag             status  lastmodified
517         Blue            0       2019-02-02 15:00:23
517         Monthly Sale    0       2019-02-02 15:00:23
517         Green           1       2019-02-03 12:00:55
517         Synthetic       1       2019-02-03 12:00:55
517         Clearance       1       2019-02-03 12:00:55
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h1TdK8LGzeCiB9PH4QSvZM/1)

**Update**

Since `producttags_temp` is a temporary table, you can't use it more than once in a MySQL query. As long as `lastmodified` dates are later in that table than `producttags`, you can use this query instead:

```
SELECT tag_temp as Tag, 
           productid_temp as productID, 
           MAX(lastmodified_temp) as lastmodified, 
           MAX(status)
FROM   (SELECT producttags_temp.tag_temp, 
               producttags_temp.productid_temp, 
               producttags_temp.lastmodified_temp, 
               1 AS status 
        FROM   producttags_temp 
        WHERE  productid_temp = 517 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT producttags.tag, 
               producttags.productid, 
               producttags.lastmodified, 
               0 AS status 
        FROM   producttags 
        WHERE  productid = 517) t 
GROUP  BY tag_temp, productid_temp
ORDER  BY lastmodified;
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h1TdK8LGzeCiB9PH4QSvZM/2)

Comment: I like the output.  I can work with the output.  Thank you. Testing with it now. Here's the pure SQL syntax I used to test and results https://pastebin.com/xaG2X3dc .. doesn't seem to work with a TEMPORARY tabl, and not getting the same output for some reason (doesn't bring back all the rows from producttags).. Going to mess with it a little bit more it seems close to what I was looking to output.

Comment: Yeah I'm not exactly sure.  Because `517` is one of many `productID`'s I had to add some clauses to work with the full table, and, leading from my previous comment, I messed around with creating a secondary temporary table `temp_producttags_temp` to do the JOIN your answer illustrated. Got it almost working, but could not figure out how to bring back `lastmodified` dates with a `0` `status`.  https://pastebin.com/bzWzbZCm

Comment: @BrianBruman you can't include `lastmodified` in the `UNION` part of the query as it will give you duplicate `Tag` values if they have different `lastmodified` dates.

Comment: @BrianBruman is there any way you can post some more comprehensive data? this query works with the data you have provided, it's not really possible to debug without seeing data which exhibits a problem.

Comment: @BrianBruman in your second pastebin you should add `AND p1.lastmodified_temp = t.lastmodified` to the `JOIN` condition for `producttags`

Comment: Trying.. `p1` represents `producttags` which doesn't have a `lastmodified_temp`, only a `lastmodified`, so that doesn't seem to be working.. tried some other variants but now it's only bringing back rows from the `producttags_temp` table..

Comment: @BrianBruman sorry, yes that should have been `lastmodified`, changed the `p2` in the cut & paste but forgot that.

Comment: I'll work with this.  As I said it doesn't seem to be working with a temporary table.  I got the `lastmodified` values coming through.  I feel stupid for asking the question multiple times :)

Comment: @BrianBruman if you can make a dbfiddle example I'm happy to try and help you debug the temporary table issue

Comment: I posted a query below based off my previous post. Never worked with temporary tables before so It's been a bit daunting.  Any comment?

Comment: @BrianBruman I see what the problem is, my query uses `producttags_temp` twice which is not allowed for temporary tables (a strange MySQL limitation). What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Nick Yeah I thought that was strange as well.  5.7.21. Standard WAMP installation from when. Is there any reason to not go to 8.0?

Comment: @bbruman well with 8.0 you can work around the temporary table problem with a CTE. I guess if you didn't upgrade you could always just create a normal table and add a `DROP TABLE` command once you're done...

Comment: @Nick Yeah I was just reading into that. Thanks for the tip honestly didn't even know 8.0 was released.  As for the `DROP TABLE` that seems very clunky as well.. As far as 5.7 is there something wrong with the answer/query I posted below? It seems to be giving me the same results with only one `SELECT` on the two compared tables

Comment: @bbruman There are a couple of issues with your query; when I run it I get the `Synthetic` row appearing twice. But as long as the last modified dates are more recent in the temporary table, you can use this query: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h1TdK8LGzeCiB9PH4QSvZM/2

Comment: Thanks man that works beautifully  I'm sure there are added benefits to using `COALESCE` and different types of `JOIN`s, Something I'd probably have to mess around with to get a good understanding of.  That one though, I don't see how it could fail - and it's easier to read, so I think that is the one. Also a thanks to you and @Barmar for calling me out :)

Comment: @bbruman If that's working I'll update my answer with it so it's there for anyone who comes long in the future and sees this question.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to meddle together this with help from everyone, seems to have that desired output.

```
-- Temporary Table Creation
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE producttags_temp AS SELECT Tag AS Tag_temp, productID AS productID_temp, lastmodified AS lastmodified_Temp FROM producttags LIMIT 0;
-- Insert Rows
INSERT INTO `producttags_temp` (`Tag_temp`, `productID_temp`, `lastmodified_Temp`) VALUES ('Green', 517, NOW());
INSERT INTO `producttags_temp` (`Tag_temp`, `productID_temp`, `lastmodified_Temp`) VALUES ('Synthetic', 517, NOW());
INSERT INTO `producttags_temp` (`Tag_temp`, `productID_temp`, `lastmodified_Temp`) VALUES ('Clearance', 517, NOW());

-- Actual Query
   SELECT tag_temp as Tag, 
           productid_temp as productID, 
           lastmodified_temp as lastmodified, 
           status 
FROM   (SELECT producttags_temp.tag_temp, 
               producttags_temp.productid_temp, 
               producttags_temp.lastmodified_temp, 
               1 AS status 
        FROM   producttags_temp 
        WHERE  productid_temp = 517 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT producttags.tag, 
               producttags.productid, 
               producttags.lastmodified, 
               0 AS status 
        FROM   producttags 
        WHERE  productid = 517) t 
GROUP  BY Tag 
ORDER  BY lastmodified
```

Output:

```
╔══════════════╦════════════════╦═════════════════════╦════════╗
║     Tag      ║    productID   ║     lastmodified    ║ status ║
╠══════════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════════╬════════╣
║ Blue         ║            517 ║ 2019-03-02 23:19:08 ║      0 ║
║ Monthly Sale ║            517 ║ 2019-03-02 23:19:08 ║      0 ║
║ Green        ║            517 ║ 2019-03-08 19:37:46 ║      1 ║
║ Synthetic    ║            517 ║ 2019-03-08 19:37:46 ║      1 ║
║ Clearance    ║            517 ║ 2019-03-08 19:37:47 ║      1 ║
╚══════════════╩════════════════╩═════════════════════╩════════╝
```